# I need a POP3 to Office 365 connector

Tags: email, office365, pop3

My company has very strict rules for mail protocols.  We use a piece of software that is only able to connect to a POP3 account, and that protocol is not allowed.

Could I find some kind of connector/relay or whatever, that would allow me to have an Office 365 account, where this piece of software would be able to connect to the Office 365 and deliver it to our software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the combination of [Python](http://python.org) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to set up a local [Django POP3 server](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/203/) and act as a gateway to the Office 365 services, then use the Office 365 API from Python using the methods explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exchangedev/office-365-apis-and-python-part-3-mail-and-calendar-api) in [this series](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exchangedev/office-365-apis-and-python-part-1-oauth2).

Comment: Dose that mean no out of the box software exsist for this type of setup?

Comment: Not that I know of - it is not exactly the most common sort of requirement that you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of an off-the-shelf email client and local POP3 server.

The OTS mail client would use an allowed protocol other than POP3 to retrieve the mail from Office365. It would then use rules to forward the mail to a local SMTP server, which would then serve it up to your "piece of software" with POP3.

Office 365 has a POP3 interface I'm pretty sure, can't you just get your company to relax that rule?